# Is there any way to know if a function result is being assigned to a blank identifier?

Tags: go

Consider this case:

```golang
func main() {
  _, f := test()
  fmt.Println(f)
}

func test() (a, b string) {
  return "hey", "there"
}
```

Is there any way for the `test` function to know that the first result is not being assigned to any variable?

Comment: No, there's no way. Out of curiosity, why would your function need to know that?

Comment: Probably because the result that the function should be returning may pass through some extensive computation; So in a GraphQL-style thing; I'd like to the function to know which results are actually required so that it cuts out the non-essential parts. Is there any other way around this issue?